# What is the correct terminology for "configuration information" in a test report

Tags: terminology, test-report

I work as a HW quality control guy but for the first time I am the one who should produce the report.
I have no template but definitely there needs to be something like "device version" information (e.g. HW revision X, Firmware 1.1.3 etc.). Is there a common term in English/ technical English that describe that? I was thinking about "Device specification" or "Configuration" but neither sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

> HW revision X, Firmware 1.1.3 etc.

I use the term 'Environment'. It looks like JIRA does too, [source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/what-is-an-issue-270829373.html).

Comment: Yes, environment is a good term. Improvising it, you can use either 'Test Environment Specification' or 'Test Environment Configuration'. This what we generally use in our test reports.

Answer (score 0):

Get previous report for the same or similar project, and follow established precedents, using terminology other people in your company use. If you cannot, and English is not your first language, talk to some native English speaker in your company.

Answer (score 0):

In general, "Test item" is the subject of testing.

Also "Test item configuration" or "Test item version".

There is a IEEE standard (829) which offers quite a comprehensive outline. They use "Test items and their identifiers"

Answer (score 0):

If you providing this report(document) for end customers then "x.x.xV Setup Guide/Help".

If you providing this report(document)for internal test team "x.x.xV Configuration Guide"

If you providing report for external technical team "Test items and identfiers" better use IEEE standerds.